# Is it possible to load PHP_MSSQL.dll on php 5.3?

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I need to get the mssql_connect function available on a machine, and would like to load a newer php distro than 5.2.x

Does anyone know if it is possible to somehow load this driver on a`Windows 7(x64)` box, using `php 5.3 VC9` ?

Googling around led me to believe that it is possible, but the obvious

```
[PhP_MSSQL(EXPERIMENTAL!!)]
extension=php_mssql.dll
```

Inclusion in the php.ini file only leads to an error

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_mssql.dll'
- The specified module could not be found.
in Unknown on line 0
```

Including the ntwdblib.dll lead me to this error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mssql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
These options need to match
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use the MS sanctioned/developed MS SQL PHP drivers (php_sqlsrv.dll)? Or do you have a codebase littered with code using this older lib?

Comment: Codebases are fun things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP seems to have a FreeTDS driver for 5.3 VC9, so that seems to have solved my problems. It works too!

I have no doubt it will one day break deep down inside, on some obscure and complex function though.

Answer (score 0):

The clue to the problem is in the error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mssql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC9
These options need to match                         <---- the reason
```

You're running a build of PHP built with the VC9 toolchain. The `php_mssql.dll` DLL you have is built using the VC6 toolchain.

You can't mix them.